# Using (conf) file to exchange variables between python scripts?

Tags: python

I'd like to have one python script running (sometimes) that will read button presses (from a wiimote) and update a conf file such that another python script can use that file to adjust lighting brightness.

I'm guessing the *best* way to have two python scripts exchange/share variables would be to use sockets between the two scripts, or perhaps an intermediate SQL db, yes?

(Edit: I guess I'm looking to share these variables between *more* than two scripts.)

If so, I expect I'll eventually get there. Ultimately my setup will span multiple Pi nodes, and involve probably hundreds of such variables updating at various frequencies... So I'd like some input on longterm solutions that will handle this at scale.

But I'm relatively new, and was hoping I could just get this relatively simple solution working well enough with ConfigParser to troubleshoot other aspects of the setup for now.

I can get the lighting script to read my conf file variable and take that 10-bit int and adjust the lighting just fine.

But I'm having trouble with the wiimote script.

The basic code in question gets the existing int from the conf file just fine, increments it by one (when I press the "+" button on the wiimote for example) just fine, and even writes the new int back to the conf file just fine... once.

Upon a second button press I get an "argument of type 'int' is not iterable" error.

```
if (buttonPress):
    b = config.getint('levels', 'ch00') 
    b += 1
    config.set('levels', 'ch00', b)
    with open(wiimote.conf, "w") as config_file:
        config.write(config_file)
```

Comment: There seems to be a number of issues with your code:  `If` instead of `if`, `with.open` instead of `with open`, are you sure you are running this code?  Can you indicate which line the exception is occurring on please?

Comment: Sorry, both "If" instead of "if" and "with.open" instead of "with open" were transcription mistakes... I'm using Stack Exchange on mobile, and can't copy/paste my code. I've edited my question to correct those, and will comment again when I check where the exception occurs.

Comment: The exception occurs on the 2nd line here; b = config.getint ... the second time this if section is run.

Comment: You're basically rolling your own message queue system by doing this. Why not look at something dedicated to the job? RabbitMQ is popular.

Comment: Having just skimmed a RabbitMQ tutorial, while message queueing does seem worthwhile to learn and know (thank you), it seems to add a significant degree of complexity. And me being rather new/and a DIYer, may well just lead to more obstacles for me at this stage.

Comment: And me being rather new/and a DIYer, may well just lead to more obstacles for me at this stage. If I could edit a config file, it could be written/edited to via several scripts, such as from one communicating with a wiimote, another via a hardwired rotary encoder, and/or just ssh'ing in and manually editing the config file. And on the other end, any and all scripts could read what those various inputs had set the lighting level to be, and adjust it accordingly, as well as keeping a record via another script of the levels over time. This would survive reboots and editing of any of the scripts.

Comment: But to accomplish this with RabbitMQ, it seems I'd have to incorporate the MQ client code into each of the input scripts (no big deal), and then message to an intermediate script that would have to store and modify the various inputs, and need to be running 24/7, in order for the scripts that would need to get messages from that intermediate script to be able to be stopped and edited as I slowly develop the system as a whole. I can do all of that, I suppose... but it still seems significantly more complex than simply editing an integer in a file. If it can be done.

Comment: And I can simply edit a single integer in a file, but I had hoped to have some number of integers in a single file to edit individually, versus a separate file for each one.

Comment: I think you'll have a massively higher risk of synchronization problems and write conflicts if you use plain file editing. You'll effectively have to implement your own transactional system, or have exclusive locks that make a number of your services get stuck waiting, potentially resulting in deadlock if you ever need two files. I haven't done that much with queues, but I'm pretty confident that what you're talking about is just pushing messages and then reading/consuming them. A lot of the complexity you read about with queues comes from performance under very high load.

Answer (score 0):

Socket could be a good idea to exchange data between to Python programs, it's lightweight and doesn't require anything else than Python to run. It can also handle large amount of data without hassle.